# Is this true: $\mathbb{Q}$[$\sqrt[4]{5}$(1-$i$)] = $\mathbb{Q}$[$\sqrt[4]{5}$(1+$i$)]

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$\mathbb{Q}$[$\sqrt[4]{5}$(1-$i$)] = $\mathbb{Q}$[$\sqrt[4]{5}$(1+$i$)] ?

Having no clue how to proceed. Obviously shouldn't be using plain algebra to expand the terms? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

They are not equal. Notice that both fields have degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, being generated by roots of the irreducible polynomial $x^4 + 20$ (the roots of $x^4 + 4$ are $\pm 1 \pm i$). If they were equal, then this field would contain $\sqrt[4]{5}(1+i) + \sqrt[4]{5}(1-i) = 2\sqrt[4]{5}$, and hence $\sqrt[4]{5}$, so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5}(1+i))$ since both have degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. But $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, while $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5}(1+i))$ is not.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: the two generating elements are roots of $x^4+20$. What are the other roots? What is the splitting field of $x^4+20$? What is its degree?

Comment: This number of questions in this post is greater than the number of answers! ;-)

Comment: @RobertLewis: I think giving answers outright to elementary questions like this is just wrong and robs the OP of the opportunity to think on his own, in addition to promoting the use of this site as a place to find people who do your homework for free. Asking the right questions, on the other hand, can guide OP to find the answers on his own.